# Using Webhelpers in mako template in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, mako, akhet

How do I use Webhelpers in a Mako template in my Pyramid app?

---

In Pylons I had global helper variable `h` to use in my templates so I could simply do:

```
${h.stylesheet_link("/css/default.css")}
```

given I import `stylesheet_link` from `webhelpers.html.tags` in Pylons `lib/helpers.py`

I don't want to go with [Akhet](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/akhet/dev/) and replicate full Pylons behavior but simply I'd like to get some base (recommended?) usage of a package that's (cite) *officially endorsed, but not Pyramid add-on.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cookbook in the docs refers to this here

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/templates/templates.html

You basically inject the helpers using a before-render event so that it's available in your templates. Hope that helps.

Comment: Right what I was looking for, thank you. My problem with Pyramid documentation is often I simply can't figure out *what* and *where* to search...